# Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, compiler-warnings

I have been dragging around this build warning for quite some time and I would like to get rid of it when building my Xamarin.Forms.Ios project.

I get the warning

> "/Applications/Visual
> Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/MSBuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(5,5):
> Warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of
> "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.  These reference
> conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to
> detailed. (MSB3277) (BB.App.iOS)"

In the build log I find the following statement.

```
There was a conflict between "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
        "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
        References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Microsoft.CSharp.dll].
            /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Microsoft.CSharp.dll
              Project file item includes which caused reference "/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/Microsoft.CSharp.dll".
                Microsoft.CSharp
        References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
            /Users/sjorsmiltenburg/.nuget/packages/automapper/10.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/AutoMapper.dll
              Project file item includes which caused reference "/Users/sjorsmiltenburg/.nuget/packages/automapper/10.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/AutoMapper.dll".
                /Users/sjorsmiltenburg/.nuget/packages/automapper/10.0.0/lib/netstandard2.0/AutoMapper.dll
                /Users/sjorsmiltenburg/_Sources_BookaBooka/BB.App/BB.App/bin/Debug/netstandard2.0/BB.App.dll
```

I could find a similar issue [on android](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1261) but here the cause is related to newtonsoft.json having a reference to the old CSharp.dll.

What I read here is that Automapper is referencing Microsoft.CSharp 4.7 (which I can find in the  nuget references of my main project), but I Can't figure out where the Microsoft.CSharp 2.0.5.0 reference comes from.

I can drill down the nuget - reference tree in my main project but not in my XF.ios project. In my ios.proj file i find no reference to CSharp.dll

Comment: I am in the same boat. I have 2 of these warnings one exactly wha you have and they have been bothering me for a while. I finally got rid of all my other warnings and now these just really annoy me. Hope we can find a solution soon.

Comment: I hope this automatically goes away when migrating to maui